# Clicking button doesn't switch pages in Android

Tags: kotlin

Code:

```
class ProfileFragment : Fragment() {
    
        lateinit var ProfileSetting : ImageView

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false)
            ProfileSetting = view.findViewById(R.id.imgProfileSetting)
            return view
    
        }
    
        }
```

Clicking the button doesn't switch the page in app.

`imgProfileSetting` is button.

Comment: Where is the button?

Comment: imgprofilesetting

Answer (score 0):

Your `Button` does not have any `ClickListener`, implement it :

```
ProfileSetting.setOnClickListener {
//Do your stuff
        }
```